# npm install timesout when running docker build . on windows 11

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, windows-11

Running npm install timesout running docker build . on windows 11.
I don't know what is wrong. I am using wsl2 containers.

```html
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a networking issue (slow connection speed) you can add `npm config set timeout 6000000` to the `RUN` command and it should help, if it's a host issue ("internet not being passed to the container") you can add `--network=host` to your build command.